# Can't run ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am struggling with ProcessBuilder folks! I want to run the utility 'nativetoascii' in. I can run it on the command line and also via Runtime.exec() with no problems.

My code is:

```
'     
  String command = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_32\\bin\\native2ascii\"";
  String encoding = " -encoding ";
  String utf8 = "UTF8 ";
  String inputFile = "C:\\Users\\joe\\Desktop\\resources\\encoding\\orig.properties ";
  String outputFile ="C:\\Users\\joe\\Desktop\\resources\\encoding\\convertedViaProcessBuilder.properties";

  List<String> commandArgs = new ArrayList<String>();
  commandArgs.add(command);
  commandArgs.add(encoding);
  commandArgs.add(utf8);
  commandArgs.add(inputFile);
  commandArgs.add(outputFile);

  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(commandArgs);
  Process p = builder.start();
  p.waitFor();
```

I have also written code to read the output from the process and it says:

```
Usage: native2ascii [-reverse] [-encoding encoding] [inputfile [outputfile]]
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong with the command and its arguments. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried without spaces around your command arguments. Since the arguments are already "parsed" I don't think you should have the spaces there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second argument is `" -encoding "` which it would be `"-encoding"`  Spaces matter when you run a command. ;)

Comment: And likewise you don't need the quotes around the command name - on the command line you need them to tell the command line parser that it's one name even though it contains spaces, but with ProcessBuilder you pass the arguments as a list so there's no parser involved.

Comment: that fixed it, I can't believe I was stumped by something so basic! Thanks folks.

Comment: @user1412992 Its easy to ignore spaces as not really being there. ;)